# What does normalizedPath refer to and how can I draw it over an image in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiimage, cgpath

I have two images, one that is a monochrome one which is a mask and another one with full color. What I need to do is find the `CGRect` of the mask (white pixels) in the other full color one.

What I did is to first find the contour of the mask using the `Vision` framework. Now, this returns a `CGPath` which is normalised. How can I translate this path into coordinates to the other image? Both have been scaled the same way to make them the same size so the translation should be "easy" but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Vision framework uses normalized to mean lower left is origin, values go from 0 to 1.0. And "for observations like landmarks in a face rect, these coordinates are relative to parent observations" - does that help?